# Get Backbone.js to make a POST request for a new module with an specified id attribute

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I'm having an issue getting Backbone to send a **POST** request for a newly created model for which I specified an **id** parameter.

For those wondering why would I need that, what happens actually in the API is that a tag that already exists in the, say http://api.example.com/tags/tag_id is beeing referenced for a given content type, eg. http://api.example.com/conent/content_id/tags. What I'm therefore trying to get Backbone to do is to make a POST request to http://api.example.com/conent/content_id/tags/tag_id when a model with that id is being created in the tags collection.

Comment: Ok, it's a little hard to understand what your problem is but am I right that, when a new **tag** model is created, you then want to call the **content** API and pass the newly created tag ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more RESTfull you should send `POST http://api.example.com/conent/content_id/tags` because `POST  http://api.example.com/conent/content_id/tags/tag_id` means updating of existed resource.

But if you want to do it in this way you can specify `url` of collection:

```
var Content = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/content'
});

var Tag = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Tags = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function(){
    return this.content.url() + '/tags';
  },
  initialize: function(models, options){
    this.content = options.content;
  }
});

var content = new Content({id: 12}),
    tags = new Tags([], {content: content});

tags.create({id: 25});
// => PUT/PATCH http://api.example.com/content/12/tags/25
```

It is because when your model have id Backbone is thinking that is is already existed model and trying to update it. One of the solution is pass `type`:

```
tags.create({id: 25}, {type: 'POST'});
// => POST http://api.example.com/content/12/tags/25
```